# Replace all instances of "null" with null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native, mongodb-compass

After importing data into mongo, fields that were supposed to be of type null ended up being strings "null", is there a command or query to replace all instances of that string with a null value?

I have something like this

```
TestModel.updateMany({ test: 'null' },{ $set: { test: null } })
```

But it throws this error

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "null" at path "test" for model "TestModel"
```

I tried it in other fields where they are all string and it works, but the field "test" can be an Objectid or a null

EDIT:

document:

```
const TestSchema = new Schema({
    test: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}
});
module.exports = db.model('TestModel', TestSchema);
```

Comment: Please post a sample document showing the `test` field. Also, specify where you are running this command from (shell, node, Mongoose, etc.).

Comment: @prasad_ i tried running that command using mongoose, but i am looking for a solution on either mongoose or the shell

Comment: That command may work using shell. Mongoose is trying to convert "null" to an objectId, shell won't. ```db.TestModel.updateMany({ test: 'null' },{ $set: { test: null } }, {multi: true})```

Comment: Does it need to be explicitly set to `null`, or is having the field omitted from the document sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
TestModel.updateMany({ test: 'null' }, { $set: { test: undefiend } })
```